# How remove submit button and automatically load model box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just need remove submit button and open model box without submit button, i checked the code but it's little big script I'm confused what i do. I can use onload Event?. The script is an indian payment gateway service(Razorpay). I try to modify it's not working, I need the exact way. I'm new in JS. I don't know where i can modify with onload event?

This is my JS script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    function showModal(response) {
        $('#response').html(response);
        $('html, body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
        $('.modal-container').show().prop('offsetHeight');
        $('.modal-container').addClass('shown');
    }
    function hideModal() {
        $('html, body').css('overflow', '');
        $('.modal-container').removeClass('shown');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.modal-container').hide();
        }, 300)
        document.getElementById("btn-razorpay").disabled = false;
    }
    $('.close').click(hideModal);
    // global method
    function createOrder(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "#redirectUrl#?action=create_order&page_id=#pageID#",
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(order) {   
                if (order.hasOwnProperty('error')){
                    showModal(order['error']);
                }
                else{
                    order.handler = function(payment){
                        $('#razorpay_payment_id').val(payment.razorpay_payment_id);
                        $('#razorpay_signature').val(payment.razorpay_signature);
                        var form_data = $('form').serializeArray();

                        $.ajax({
                            url: "#redirectUrl#", 
                            data: form_data,
                            type: 'POST',
                            success: function(response){
                                showModal(response);
                            }
                        });
                    };
                }
                // On dismissing the popup, enable the button again
                order.modal = {
                    ondismiss: function(){
                        document.getElementById("btn-razorpay").disabled = false;
                    }
                };
                // After order is created, open checkout
                openCheckout(order);
            }
        })
    }
    // global method
    function openCheckout(order) {
        var razorpayCheckout = new Razorpay(order);
        razorpayCheckout.open();
    }
    function disableRzpButton(){
        document.getElementById("btn-razorpay").disabled = true;
    }
    function addEvent(element, evnt, funct){
        if (element.attachEvent)
            return element.attachEvent('on' + evnt, funct);
        else
            return element.addEventListener(evnt, funct, false);
    }
    addEvent(document.getElementById("btn-razorpay"), 'click', createOrder);
    addEvent(document.getElementById("btn-razorpay"), 'click', disableRzpButton);
})
```

Comment: What is your modal looks like? Do you have HTML of that?

Comment: It is popup window a payment gateway

Comment: remove your button *type* if it is set to submit and add an *onclick* event to the button instead to call the function that opens your modal. If that's not what you're looking for, please elaborate on *"remove submit button"* and provide an example of the html code in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your submit button you need to add an event clicker which will call the showModal function.

```
<div id="submit" onclick="showModal()">Submit</div>
```

Maybe, something like this. This is assuming you have that script included in your HTML code.